# Exporting in JSON Format

Tags: python, json, export

I can export my data as CSV using:

```
df.reset_index().to_csv('MYDATASET.csv')
```

How can I export my result in JSON Array Format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use orient='records'

print df.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')